DAC Based current source not working as expected
I am designing a DAC controlled current source based on this material. My DAC maximum output voltage is 3.3 V. Maximum output current is 20 mA.
But I am getting only 2.3 μA. My circuit is given below.

Below is my calculation. May I know where I went wrong?

EDIT 1
I am not able to find the proper MOSFET model in tin ti. So I changed the MOS with BJTs. But no change in result.

EDIT 2
As Andy suggested, I redesigned R3, and it is working now.


Looks like the simulation is right. Why do you imagine, in any possible way, that using a 322.9k resistor on one side with a 2k resistor on the other would do anything else? What is 2.3 uA times 322.9k compared to 371.6 uA times 2k?

The power MOSFET you are using (2N6804) has a gate-source threshold voltage that can be as much as -4 volts. This means that to start to activate it, the gate voltage might need to be lower than the source voltage by 4 volts. Your supply is only 3.3 volts so already you are having design problems: -

But it gets worse because, for 20 mA load current the voltage dropped across R3 will lower the source voltage and, you will need an even lower gate voltage to control the current.
But, you have a value for R3 of what appears to be 322,9 k and I presume this means 322.9 kΩ and, that will never be right for 20 mA control.

I think there are problems with T1 as well, not nearly enough voltage swing from the opamp to control its gate.

I updated the question.Could you please check.I am not able to find proper mosfet models in TINA

@Confused you have changed R3 to 322 ohms. At 20 mA, the volt drop across it will be 6.44 volts so, how can you expect this to be accommodated with a 3.3 volt supply rail. A BJT is going to be the better route but, 322 ohms is still about ten times too big to get anything like 20 mA. You appear to be getting 4.06 mA and, that will drop 1.31 volts and, that is about as good as it will get. Go for something like 33 ohm and a BJT.

@Andyaka,I redesigned R3 and it is working now.In my real life R4 will be a PT100. Do I need to take care any other things.

@Confused at PT100 has a resistance of 100 ohm at zero celcius so, if you want to push 20 mA through it, there will be 2 volts lost across the load and, not much room for control. At 100 celcius there will be 2.76 volts across it and, I have doubts whether a 3.3 volt supply is going to be big enough.

@Andyaka,For setting the Iout Rload is not coming anywhere in the equation.Ideally Iout should be independent of Rload.May I know how to redesign this for a wide variety of load

The formula does not require the value of the load resistor but, if you don't have sufficient supply voltage, the formula is null and void. Wide resistive value loads requires a supply that is greater than Rload_maximum x Iout_maximum. It's simple ohms law; you can't conjure up voltages across your load from an insufficient power supply.
